# Layering Conditional Formatting Based on Another Cell Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I already have a conditional format for a heat scale for each separate row. I want to layer that by highlighting the cell if its corresponding cell on another sheet is above $5,000.

The sheet I have the conditional formatting for has a heat scale for monthly percentages of the total reporting period. I want to layer that by highlighting the percentages that also are above $5,000 value on the corresponding month's financial statement.

For example, revenue for the month of June was 20% of the total revenue for the reporting period and also over $5,000. So that cell would have the deepest color for the heat scale and would be bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If two separate rules apply different types of formatting and **`Stop If True`** <sup>*</sup> is **unchecked**, they can be layered.  For example, one applies a background color to a cell and the other bolds all text.
2. If the two rules apply the same type of formatting or **`Stop If True`** <sup>*</sup> is **checked**, then the first rule will always take precedence. For example, if two rules both change the text color, the first rule that matches will be applied (the colors will not be blended).
3. If you want to customize the behavior for a subset of cells, you will need to edit the higher precedence rule with an exception or order the rules in such a way as to give precedence to the one you want to win in a tie.

---

<sup>*</sup> **Stop If True**
In order for Excel to consider additional rules for the same cell once another rule's  conditions have been met, the **Stop If True** option must be unchecked.

Comment: @gns100 you may wish to remove the comment now that it did its job.  Also, you have a typo: *"if unchecked then the **first** rule that meets the condition wins."*